# Venting Range Hood into Attic Space, Temporarily

Tags: attic, vent, ducts, range, hood

My ductless recirculating range hood broke, and I have to install the replacement.  I love to cook, so I'm installing a roof vent for a ducted hood.
The range hood I bought has good filtering for grease and carbon filters.

It's winter in MN, and I can't easily work on the roof for a couple of months. Here's my question:

Is it ok for me to vent this into the attic space with minimal use for a couple of months?  I understand there are downsides of venting a range hood into the attic, but I need to know if it's fine for a short time.

Comment: I would vent into a cheap flex tube and run that as close to ventilated air source as possible. That at least contains and catches the condensate, and you can jsut dispose of it later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The biggest issue you have venting into the attic is warm, moist air being blown into a somewhat closed area (aside from the grease and particles you have a filter for).  If the attic space you vent into is large, and has good ventilation this shouldn't be an issue.  If you have to vent into a small portion of the attic and it looks like the moist air will get caught by insulation then there *might* be an issue depending on how much it's used.

The warm air will condense readily in a cold attic, so knowing that, look around and imagine what the moist air will do.  The other issue is that things can come up and "only temporary" ends up being 3-4 years...  Ultimately you'll have to answer for yourself, but for light use an "only a couple months", it's probably fine.

Comment: I'm in Minnesota and I endorse this message (if not our current weather).

Comment: It's called "temporary-permanent" and not to be employed for any length of time if it will create a greasy fire hazard. If it's only light use then it isn't necessary. ... (two years later) *Hey man, why does your whole house smell like a playpen at McDonalds?*